# Does component-wise convergence in distribution imply the random vector converges in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$. Similarly, $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of random variables such that $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} Y$. Is it true that $\left(X_n, Y_n\right) \xrightarrow{d} \left(X,Y\right)$? Also, is the converse true?

Answer (score 7):

No. If $X_n=X=-Y_n=Y$ for all $n$ where $X$ has normal distribution with mean  $0$ and variance $1$ then $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not converge in distribution to $(X,Y)$. This is because $X_n+Y_n$ does not tend to $X+Y$ in distribution. Converse is true and it follows from the fact that $(x,y) \to x$ and $(x,y) \to y$ are continuous maps.

Comment: Under the additional hypothesis that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent both the implications are true.

Comment: Is it true that $X_n+Y_n$ does not converge in distribution to $X+Y$ because of the following argument: Since $X_n$ and $-Y_n$ are independent we have $$\Phi_{X_n+(-Y_n)}(z)=\Phi_{X_n}(z)\cdot \Phi_{-Y_n}(z)=\Phi_X(z)\cdot \Phi_Y(z)=\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)=\exp(-z^2)$$ But on the other Hand $\Phi_{X+Y}(z)$ is not defined since $X+Y=0$ and this has no density?

Comment: sorry I'm not really used to this convergence in distribution stuff yet.

Comment: Constant r.v.'s (and more generally r.v's taking only countably many values) are called discrete r.v.'s and they have no density. So $X+Y$ has no pdf. @aprozz

Comment: sorry I don't understand this. Can't I do it with the characteristic function?

Comment: Characteristic function of $X+Y$ is $1$. Every r.v. has a characteristic function.

Comment: Hmm why is it $1$ I mean $\Phi_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^0 P_{X+Y}(dz)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. $\int 1 \mu (dz)=\mu (\mathbb R)=1$ for any probability measure $\mu$.

Comment: Ah oh sure! But then on the other hand it is correct that $\Phi_{X_n+(-Y_n)}(z)=\exp(-z^2)$? and that's what gives us that we don't have convergence in distribution

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you very much for your help. But if I would not know $\Phi_{X_n}(z)$ explicitly as here, then I only have $\Phi_{X_n}(z)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{i \langle z,X_n \rangle} dz$ right? But then if $X_n$ takes only real values is it then $\Phi_{X_n}(z)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{i z\cdot X_n} dz$ or something else? So I mean the $n$ can not disappear in the integral if we want to take the limit right?

Answer (score 0):

Not in general.

It might be e.g. that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not defined on the same probability space so that $(X_n,Y_n)$ is not properly defined. This also for $X$ and $Y$.

Be aware that here we are dealing with convergence of *distributions* and not particulary of the random variables that at most represent them (and actually can be missed). On that point there is an essential difference with convergence in probability and with convergence almost surely.

And even if that's avoided by presuppositions then the answer stays "no" (see the answer of Kavi).

If conversely $(X_n,Y_n)$ and $(X,Y)$ are random vectors with $(X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}(X,Y)$ then indeed also $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to}Y$.